# Symfony2 / FOSUserBundle: Change render variables in response without altering parent class

Tags: php, symfony, twig, fosuserbundle

One of my classes currently extends the BaseController on the FOSUserBundle, and returns the parent action. However, due to project spec, I shouldn't have the need to edit the parent class. Is there a way of sending additional variables, for twig to render, through the child response?

**Child Class:**

```
class ChangePasswordController extends BaseController
{
    public function changePasswordAction(Request $request)
    {
        $response = parent::changePasswordAction($request);

        return $response; // and 'myVariable' => $myVariable
    }
}
```

**Parent Class:**

```
class ChangePasswordController extends ContainerAware
{
    /**
     * Change user password
     */
    public function changePasswordAction(Request $request)
    {
        //lots of code.....

        return $this->container->get('templating')
                    ->renderResponse(
                    'FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword.html.'
                        .$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
                         array(
                         'form' => $form->createView()

                          //and 'myVariable' => $myVariable     

                          )
               );

    }
}
```

So to summarise, is there a way of passing something to the parent class, without changing the parent class... whilst rendering the twig view with an additional variable.

## -- Update --

Essentially I want to render a form using the FOSUserBundle changePassword action, therefore this works fine:

```
return $this->container
            ->get('templating')
            ->renderResponse(
            'FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
            array('form' => $form->createView())
        );
```

However, I want to pass more variables to the view, just like the 'form' is passed as shown above, *without* altering the **FosUserBundle ChangePassword Controller**. Therefore I have a class which inherits the that controller, adds some additional functionality and returns the parent change password action:

```
class ChangePassController extends ChangePasswordController
{
    public function changePasswordAction(Request $request)
    {
        // more code......

        $response = parent::changePasswordAction($request);
        return $response;
    }
}
```

But, like with most applications, I want to add more than just the form variable to a view template. So is there a way of passing an additional variable to the view, without altering the parent controller / action? Like (but not like) pushing 'myVariable' => $myVariable to the parent changePasswordAction return statement?

Comment: What sort of variable do you want to add?  The changePasswordAction fires FOSUserEvents::CHANGE_PASSWORD_INITIALIZE (assuming you are using the dev-master version).  So it's possible to hang a listener and inject something that twig can pick up.  Exactly how to accomplish this sort of depends on what your data is.  You might also create a twig extension and pull the data in from somewhere.  Just need a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [section in FOSUserBundle documentation](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md) that describes exactly how to do that, and from Symfony2's Cookbook, [How to use Bundle Inheritance to Override parts of a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-controllers).

In summary, create a `Bundle` class to override `FOSUserBundle` in `src`:

```
// src/Acme/UserBundle/AcmeUserBundle.php
<?php

namespace Acme\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Then, override the `ChangePasswordController` class:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ChangePasswordController as BaseController;

class ChangePasswordController extends BaseController
{
    public function changePasswordAction(Request $request)
    {
        $response = parent::changePasswordAction($request);

        return $response; // and 'myVariable' => $myVariable
    }
}
```

**--UPDATE--**

Ok I think I misread you question. Anyway what `renderResponse()` of the `templating` service does is essentially:

```
$response->setContent($this->render($view, $parameters));
```

You can see the `Class` of the `templating` service by running `app/console container:debug` which is actually the [`TwigEngine class`](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php).

So you can just re-invoke `renderResponse()` and supply you own extra parameters. eg:

```
return $this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse(
    'FOSUserBundle:ChangePassword:changePassword.html.'.$this->container->getParameter('fos_user.template.engine'),
    array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'myVariable' => $myVariable', // There you go
    ),
    $response // The previous response that has been rendered by the parent class, by this is not necessary
);
```

Comment: Not sure but I don't think that will really help because the response will already have the fully renders html.  Twig has already done it's thing.

Comment: I have tried implementing your solution, and now my twig templates don't recognise the form variable because they are declared in the parent function, which I won't have access to? I thought my re-invoking the `renderResponse()` I wouldn't have to pass the original array elements again?

Comment: urm @Cerad is right. I guess there isn't an easy way to do this without re-implementing most parts of the method.

Comment: @user2071225 - If you update your question and describe what sort of variable you need to add then we might be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Think bottom up.

You can access your data without passing it through action, using Twig Extension http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html

```
    twig.extension.user_profile:
    class: 'MyBundle\UserProfileExtension'
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager'
    tags:
        - { name: twig.extension }
```

Extension class

```
class UserProfileExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
/**
 * @var EntityManager
 */
private $entityManager;

/**
 * @param UserProfileDataService $userProfileDataService
 */
public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
{
    $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getFunctions()
{
    return array(
        new \Twig_SimpleFunction('get_my_custom_var', array($this, 'getMyCustomVar')),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getMyCustomVar()
{
    $var = $this->entityManager->getRepository('MyCustomRepository')->findOneBy(['id' => 1]);

    return $var;
}

/**
 * Returns the name of the extension.
 *
 * @return string The extension name
 */
public function getName()
{
    return 'user_profile_extension';
}
```

Template usage

```
{dump(get_my_custom_var())}
```

Answer (score -1):

if I am understanding your question correctly you should be able to set additional variables on the response like this:

```
use FOS\UserBundle\Controller\ChangePasswordController as BaseController;

class ChangePasswordController extends BaseController
{
    public function changePasswordAction(Request $request)
    {
        $response = parent::changePasswordAction($request);

        $response['myVariable'] = $myVariable;

        return $response;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why was this down voted? It works and is a simple solution.